# Shell Context Menus

Tags: c#, contextmenu, windows-shell

I am currently running a `Windows 7 x64 machine`.

I have written the following code to add a context menu on right click:

```
    RegistryKey rKey = Registry.ClassesRoot.OpenSubKey("Directory\\Background\\shell", true);
    String[] names = rKey.GetSubKeyNames();
    foreach (String s in names)
    {
        System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(s); 
    }
    RegistryKey newKey = rKey.CreateSubKey("Your Application");
    RegistryKey newSubKey = newKey.CreateSubKey("command");
    newSubKey.SetValue("", "C:\\Windows\\System32\\notepad.exe");
    newSubKey.Close();
    newKey.Close();
    rKey.Close();
```

If I repeat the procedure directly on the registry, it works, but not via this.

I am also able to access the registry, as I have added a snippet that tells lists all subkeys that I require, but simply does not add one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have tested your code and it is well & good. Looks like you dont have access rights to open the registry from the code. Just follow these simple steps:

1. Close your Visual studio. Then Open it again as Run As Administrator mode. This one you can do by Right clicking on the Visual Studio link and choose Run As Administrator option.
2. Open your code and run it from there.

If you want to directly run the program from the Exe then Right click on Exe & choose Run As Administrator option.

If you don't want to do Run As Administrator, then follow these steps:

1. Add a new file to you project called App.manifest; by adding a new File from Project.
2. Add following data to that file, rest it will do the magic.

Just replace your application name with MyApplication.app. The important part is the  section. Rest is auto generated.

> ```
>   xmlns:asmv1="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1"
>   xmlns:asmv2="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v2"
>   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
>   <assemblyIdentity version="1.0.0.0" name="MyApplication.app" />
>   <trustInfo xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v2">
>     <security>
>       <requestedPrivileges xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
>         <requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator"
>       uiAccess="false" />
>       </requestedPrivileges>
>     </security>
>   </trustInfo>
> </asmv1:assembly>
> ```

Comment: Thanks, that worked. Say, I bundle this into an `.exe`., and let users create similar menus on their systems. How will I be able to 'Run as an administrator' on the fly?